# Ehcache midnight/nightly expiration strategy

Tags: java, ehcache

It's not immediately obvious to me how to set EhCache to expire an entire cache nightly/at midnight.  I can easily do this programmatically via a job of some sort, but I wanted to know if there was a more "ehcache" way of doing it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should implement it using a [Cache Extension](http://ehcache.org/documentation/cache_extensions.html)

"Cache Extensions are suitable for timing services, where you want to create a timer to perform cache operations."

Comment: I glanced at extensions, but I think cache.removeAll() + cronjob is just too easy to pass up for this case.  Thanks though.